# Localization without screenshots?

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect, screenshot

I have apps that are localized into many languages, and I'd like to upload new screenshots. The screenshots are the same for all languages but I really don't want to  upload them several times for each language to each app. I also don't really like the option of deleting and re-entering all the localized data.

What I'm trying to figure out is, if I delete all the screenshots from the other languages and only upload them in the English version, will iTunes use those for all the other localizations automatically?

Answer (score 2):

iTunesConnect will automatically display the English version (of screenshots and text) to any un-localized store.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You should upload all screenshots in English version before creating a new language in iTunes Connect. It will duplicate all screenshots from English version to new version.